# Кальулятор чисел в Java и enum-класс

Tags: java, enum

Всем привет! Начал изучать программирование на языке java, и столкнулся со следующей проблемой.
По условию,необходимо задать два числа,сохранить их в свойствах, затем реализовать в классе метод,который будет выводить сложение,вычитание, умножение этих чисел. Вывод в консоль в тестовом классе Main. Отлельно в классе Enum создается перечень операций над числами, это ADD, SUBSTRACT, MULTIPLY. Мне удается выводить операции над числами в консоль, но я не могу к получившемуся результату операции присоединить другой результат. То есть как в калькуляторе: к сумме чисел прибавить третье число, к разности чисел умножить третье число, и т.д. Кто поможет с решением? Код ниже.

```
public class ArithmeticCalculator{
public int a;
public int b;

public Arithmetical(){
this.a=a;
this.b=b;
}

public void calculate(Operation operation, int a, int b){
switch(operation){
case ADD :
System.out.println(int a + int b);
break;
case SUBSTRACT :
System.out.println(int a - int b);
break;
case MUITIPLY :
System.out.println(int a × int b);
break;
}
}
```

ENUM  класс:

```
public enum Operation{
ADD, 
SUBSTRACT,
MULTIPLY
}
```

И тестовый класс Main:

```
public class Main{
public static void main{
ArithmeticCalculator calculator = new ArithmeticCalculator();
calculator.calculate(Operation.ADD, 1,2);
calculator.calculate(Operation.SUBSTRACT, 1,2);
calculator.calculate(Operation.MULTIPLY, 1,2);
```

Comment: Чтобы что то делать с результатом операции, надо его как то сохранить. Например, вы можете этот результат возвращать из своей функции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например `calculate` вместо того, чтобы печатать результат, может возвращать его в вызывающий код (хотя и то и другое можно совместить).

```
public int calculate(Operation operation, int a, int b) {
    switch (operation) {
        case ADD : return a + b;
    ...
}
```

Тогда можно делать так

```
int sum = calculator.calculate(Operation.ADD, 1, 2);
System.out.println(sum);
// теперь вычтем что-нибудь из полученного выше sum
int dif = calculator.calculate(Operation.SUBSTRACT, sum, 2);
System.out.println(dif);
```

Comment: Спасибо Сергей!!!